# How to use MongoDb Database on Digital Ocean Server?

Tags: mongodb

I had a NodeJS based application and currently, I'm using Mongolab for database storage. It's very easy to storing, querying, reading data on mlab.

Now, I'm thinking to create an independent MongoDB server on Digital Ocean.

Digital Ocean (a cloud computing company) provides one-click creation of MongoDB server.

My ques: **How can I perform CRUD operations on Digital Ocean Server? Where to see the stored Data on Mongodb Server? Is it same as Mlab?**

In Mlab, we get a link to perform CRUD operations, which looks like:
mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@ds153719.mlab.com:53719/dbcollection

**What would be the link on MongoDB Server on Digital Ocean?**

I had read many tutorials on MongoDb but they mainly focus on interacting with mongoDb database on local storage/server. I hardly found any tutorial on step by step process to use MongoDb on cloud servers. I would prefer answers with Digial ocean Servers as they provide simple installation process.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-node-js-to-a-mongodb-database-on-a-vps

Comment: @maxli this tutorial is explaining the connections on the same server. I want to connect mongo and nodejs where Mongo is set up on an independent server. Above tutorial is simply connecting them using 127.0.0.1 IP. I had read some tutorial where they use IP of the server, not the default one. Can you give a brief overview on how it can work?